# Should IDs be nominal factors or text?

Tags: r, measurement, categorical-data, identifiability

I am getting started with R. I imported by data and R decided that my ID attribute should be a factor. While technically correct, it feels misleading to me. An ID doesn't feel like a factor with 18,327 levels- one level for every observations in the data set.

Should ID be of type factor or should they be coerced into type character?

Comment: Depends on what will you do with ID column. Without more context, this question does not have a single "correct" answer.

Comment: I will use the ID column as a key to join multiple sources of data. I do not have any other plans for it than that.